# iOS 9 Facebook SDK Parse

Tags: ios, parse-platform, facebook-ios-sdk, ios9

I am using Parse pod and it allows me to use Facebook SDK for iOS.

I want to add support for iOS 9 for my application but I faced with few migration issues.

First of all is there any some steps how to update my code.

Do I need to update Parse first? and setup Facebook pods separately?

Also I found this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9), but when I copy paste this to my .plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>facebook.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>                
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>fbcdn.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>akamaihd.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

I get some issues, Xcode says that:

> The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

Comment: Also having issues with iO9 fb and parse integration - ugh!

Comment: @Ronaldoh1 yea I am not sure why provided code from Facebook page won't work. Looks like a solution, but I can't build app.

Comment: After many many hours I got it to work. CocoaPods didn't work for me. They haven't been updated for iOS9. I used the parse starter project. I also noticed that some of the frameworks were in the folder but they weren't included in the project. I think it was the ParseFacebookUtilsV4 that wasn't included. I had to add my old code to the starter project. I made sure the Starter project worked and was able to login before I transfer my code. It was painful #sigh

Comment: I also didn't include the XML you provided above. You need to make sure you include NSAppTransportSecurity ..should be a dictionary set to Yes

Comment: @Ronaldoh1, ok thank for comments

Answer (score 0):

I think your info.plist may be like this

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
<key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
<dict>
    <key>facebook.com</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
        <true/>                
        <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
    <key>fbcdn.net</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
    <key>akamaihd.net</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>

<dict>  <------ You couldn't add two dictionaries in one <key></key>
  <key>hogehoge</key>
</dict>

<key>fugafuga</key>
```

If so, you should move hogehoge as follows.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
<key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
<dict>
    <key>facebook.com</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
        <true/>                
        <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
    <key>fbcdn.net</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
    <key>akamaihd.net</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
  </dict>
  <key>hogehoge</key>
</dict>

<key>fugafuga</key>
```